# How to close Workbench in E4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

In Eclipse RCP 3.7.x I use

```java
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close();
```

to close the workbench

in E4 there any Method to close Workbench (without button click) or how to get Workbench reference in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a 'pure' e4 application you cannot use the 3.x `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench`.

However there is a `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench` class which has a `close()` method.

You use direct injection to inject this workbench class in to your code.

For example in a command handler you might do:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(IWorkbench workbench)
{
  workbench.close();
}
```

Comment: I am Inject IWorkbench in my application this way  @Inject IWorkbench w; but i am getting Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Where are you injecting? You can only inject in things that the application model knows about (parts, handlers, ...)

Comment: In Life Cycle class of E4 application

Comment: The workbench has probably not been created at that point, wait for the application startup complete event and get it from the IEclipseContext